# Save multiple group permissions in one go

Tags: c#, .net, api

The method `SaveGroupStepPermissions(...)` is a database API class.
If an error occurs within the method the exception is trapped. Whether this is good design or not is not the scope of this question as I need to adhere to product guidelines.

I feel that this method is to complex and too lenghty. The obvious solution is to break out code into new functions, but I'm not sure how to do that in a way that is logical.

**Important**! If an error occurs the method should stop processing and return. That means both `foreach` loops must be exited.

**Note**: Input validation is performed in `InsertGroupStepPermission()` and `UpdateGroupStepPermission()`.

Feel free to suggest improvements to code and comments beside the main question!

```
public static List<EventItem> SaveGroupStepPermissions(string connectionString, int companyID, List<Group> groups, List<GroupStepPermissions> gsp)
{
    var result = new List<EventItem>();
    result.Add(new EventItem("Insert Step permissions"));
    result.Add(new EventItem("Update Step permissions"));
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction("ProductName.GSP.cid" + companyID.ToString()))
            {
                foreach (Group group in groups)
                {
                    foreach (GroupStepPermissions stepPermission in gsp)
                    {
                        if (stepPermission.RowID == 0) //new permission that does not exist in the database. (INSERT)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                InsertGroupStepPermission(conn, tran, stepPermission, companyID, group.ID);
                                result[0].SubEvents.Add(new EventSubItem("Added rights for '" + group.Name + "' in step '" + stepPermission.StepTitle + "'", StatusEnum.OK, "Insert OK", stepPermission));
                            }
                            catch (Exception x)
                            {
                                result[0].SubEvents.Add(new EventSubItem("Failed to add rights for '" + group.Name + "' in step '" + stepPermission.StepTitle + "'", StatusEnum.Failed, x.Message, stepPermission));
                                throw;
                            }
                        }
                        else //Existing stepPermission. (UPDATE)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                UpdateGroupStepPermission(conn, tran, stepPermission, companyID, group.ID);
                                result[1].SubEvents.Add(new EventSubItem("Updated rights for '" + group.Name + "' in step '" + stepPermission.StepTitle + "'", StatusEnum.OK, "Update OK", stepPermission));
                            }
                            catch (Exception x)
                            {
                                result[1].SubEvents.Add(new EventSubItem("Failed to update rights for '" + group.Name + "' in step '" + stepPermission.StepTitle + "'", StatusEnum.Failed, x.Message, stepPermission));
                                throw;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } //End outer for
                tran.Commit(); //important :)
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception x)
    {
        var eItem = new EventItem("Failed to save step permissions");
        eItem.SubEvents.Add(new EventSubItem("Error: " + x.Message));
        result.Add(eItem);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your catch: `x.message` should be `x.Message`. There's also nothing as upsetting as only having an exception *message* when debugging - don't throw away my stack trace!

Comment: @RobH: Fixed the typo. Good point about the exception, will include it in the EventSubItem that is displayed in the application (targeted towards technical support staff)

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for fairly meaningless variable names like `gsp`, `conn`, `tran`, `eItem`,...

And `result` is equally bad, since it doesn't tell me what it contains.

`Exception x` is... unexpected. `ex` or `exc` is usually used.

---

You use `var`, but not consistently. Why `SqlConnection conn`, `Group group`, etc.?

---

I'm sure the `.ToString()` isn't necessary in `"ProductName.GSP.cid" + companyID.ToString()` -- unless you're coding to an old version of .NET.

---

Comments shouldn't tell me what is happening, but why. `//End outer for` and `//important :)` don't tell me anything useful.

Meanwhile `//new permission that does not exist in the database. (INSERT)` tells me that `if (stepPermission.RowID == 0)` isn't perhaps the best way to check if you need to do an insert or an update.

---

An `enum` shouldn't be called `StatusEnum`. Why not simply `Status`?

---

`GroupStepPermissions` is a class name, yet it seems to represent a single item. That's a big no-no.

---

Avoid concatenation:

```
"Added rights for '" + group.Name + "' in step '" + stepPermission.StepTitle + "'"
```

This is why `string.Format()` was invented.

---

Now, let's look at the whole method. You have four parameters, which is bordering on getting hard to maintain. Consider a class that contains `companyID`, `groups` and `gsp`. Note that I leave `connectionString` out of it; quite frankly I find it odd to see you pass a connectionstring to a method.

There's a lot of semi-duplicate logic, especially in `catch (Exception x)` in the insert or update. Move that to a method and call it with the required parameters.

I'd also be inclined to move everything inside `foreach (GroupStepPermissions stepPermission in gsp)` to a separate method, if only to reduce all those indentations.

I don't see the point in doing this:

```
result.Add(new EventItem("Insert Step permissions"));
result.Add(new EventItem("Update Step permissions"));
```

...if that results in having to do this:

```
result[0].SubEvents.Add
```

Name one of them `insertEventItem` and the other `updateEvenItem` and only compile the result list at the end, e.g.

```
return new List<EventItem>{ insertEventItem, updateEvenItem };
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Method signature

You should code against the lowest common type or much better against interfaces. Right now you don't use any methods of the `List<T>` class which by the way is a implementation detail which shouldn't be exposed.

Using a [`ICollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be a good fit for the return type, for the method parameters I would like to suggest using `IEnumerable<T>`. The name `gsp` is not well named you should consider to rename it to `permissions`.

This would lead to

```
public static ICollection<EventItem> SaveGroupStepPermissions(string connectionString, int companyID, IEnumerable<Group> groups, IEnumerable<GroupStepPermissions> permissions)
{

}
```

---

You are adding two `EventItem` objects to the `result` which you are later accessing by using the indexer, which can be done but this introduces two magic numbers namely `0` and `1`. This can be avoided if you assign the `EventItem`'s to well named variables like so

```
var insertItem = new EventItem("Insert Step permissions");
result.Add(insertItem);

var updateItem = new EventItem("Update Step permissions");    
result.Add(updateItem);
```

which is more clear. You should maybe adjust the variable names to fit your needs.

After we have added this `EventItem`'s we should now check if we really can and need to create a connection to the database. Validating methods parameter at least wether they are `null` should always be done if the method in question is **public** accessible.

Usually this would look like so

```
if (connectionString == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionString)); }
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString)) { throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(connectionString)} may not be empty.", nameof(connectionString)); }
```

next we need to check if the passed in `IEnumerable<T>`'s are `null` using the same pattern.

If this checks are passed we know, that all arguments are valid. If there are special cases for the `companyID` like it have to be `> 0` this check should be added as well (here an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` would be the correct exception to throw).

For your special case method throwing exceptions isn't the way to go, so I would suggest having a `private static IEnumerable<string> ValidateSaveGroupStepPermissionsParameters()` method like so

```
private static IEnumerable<string> ValidateSaveGroupStepPermissionsParameters(string connectionString, int companyID, IEnumerable<Group> groups, IEnumerable<GroupStepPermissions> permissions)
{

    if (connectionString == null) { yield return $"Parameter is null: {nameof(connectionString)}"; }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString)) { yield return $"{nameof(connectionString)} may not be empty."; }  
    if (groups == null) { yield return $"Parameter is null: {nameof(groups)}"; }
    if (permissions == null) { yield return $"Parameter is null: {nameof(permissions)}"; }  

    // possible special case for `companyID` here
}
```

which leads to

```
public static ICollection<EventItem> SaveGroupStepPermissions(string connectionString, int companyID, IEnumerable<Group> groups, IEnumerable<GroupStepPermissions> permissions)
{

    var insertItem = new EventItem("Insert Step permissions");
    result.Add(insertItem);

    var updateItem = new EventItem("Update Step permissions");    
    result.Add(updateItem);  

    var validationResults = ValidateSaveGroupStepPermissionsParameters(connectionString, companyID, groups, permissions).ToList();  

    if (validationResults.Count > 0) 
    {
        var exceptionItem = new EventItem("Failed to save step permissions");
        foreach (var msg in validationResults)
        {
            exceptionItem.SubEvents.Add(new EventSubItem($"Error: {msg}"));
        }

        result.Add(exceptionItem);
        return result;
    }
    // remaining code here
}
```

Can we now please connect to the database? Unfortunately no because we don't need to do this if either `groups` or `permissions` does not contain any items.

So let us early return in the case that there are no items like so

```
if (!groups.Any() || !permissions.Any())
{
    return result;
}
```

Instead of the inner `foreach` loop which is having that `if..else` statement I would calculate two `permission` sets like so

```
var inserts = permissions.Where(p => p.RowID == 0).ToList();
var updates = permissions.Except(inserts).ToList();
```

and use two inner `foreach` loops like so

```
foreach (Group group in groups)
{
    var groupId = group.ID;
    var groupName = group.Name;
    foreach (var permission in inserts)
    {
        try
        {
            InsertGroupStepPermission(conn, tran, permission, companyID, groupID);
            insertItem.SubEvents.Add(new EventSubItem($"Added rights for '{groupName}' in step '{permission.StepTitle}'", StatusEnum.OK, "Insert OK", permission));
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            insertItem.SubEvents.Add(new EventSubItem($"Failed to add rights for '{groupName}' in step '{permission.StepTitle}'", StatusEnum.Failed, x.Message, permission));
            throw;
        }
    }
    foreach (var permission in updates)
    {
        try
        {
            UpdateGroupStepPermission(conn, tran, permission, companyID, groupID);
            updateItem.SubEvents.Add(new EventSubItem($"Updated rights for '{groupName}' in step '{permission.StepTitle}'", StatusEnum.OK, "Update OK", permission));
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            updateItem.SubEvents.Add(new EventSubItem($"Failed to update rights for '{groupName}' in step '{permission.StepTitle}'", StatusEnum.Failed, x.Message, permission));
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The processing of these two `foreach` loops could now be extracted to separate methods.

Comment: I have to disagree with changing `groups` and `permissions` to `IEnumerable` when you're doing more with them than just enumerating. I'm pretty sure every single method in the framework taking an `IEnumerable` only calls `GetEnumerator` once. Here you're calling `GetEnumerator` twice for `groups` and three times for `permissions`. This will less than optimal if someone down the line passes in an `IQueryable`.